# How to install locale for Cygwin?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, cygwin, locale, mintty

I've installed Cygwin on window10. The language installed on window in French Canadian.

When I right-click on title bar of Cygwin window and choose *Options...*, I got this below.

[image: New Cygwin installation]

---

On Window7, cygwin is also installed and the language installed of window is French Canadian too.

On my Cygwin installation on Window 7, I have

[image: Old installation of Cygwin]

How do I install locale en_US ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That are the locale coming from Windows.

You can set a different locale in you shell startup scripts

```
$ grep LANG .bashrc
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

$ grep LANG .bash_profile
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: may be `echo 'export LANG=en_US.UTF-8' >> ~/.bashrc` as otherwise you will destroy the current content. If he does not know what grep is doing we are very low on the Cygwin knowledge

Comment: Oh Thanks. I didn't realize that it was coming from Windows. I did try to modify the locale in bash...   In cygwin, I'm calling sqlplus, a Windows programs and messages are coming in French,
You didn't answer directly the question but it helped me to understand what was happening.
Thanks